# Simple conservation of momentum question...am I right?

Tags: solution-verification, physics, classical-mechanics

I was doing a very old Applied Mathematics exam (from the 70s... yeah I lead a sad life) and came across the following problem.

*A shell is fired from a gun mounted on a carriage which is moving forward at a speed of $2m/s$.  The mass of the shell is $50\;kg$ and the combined mass of the gun and shell is $10 \;tonne$.  The recoil brings the gun and carriage to rest.  If the shell is fired horizontally, find the speed of the shell relative to the ground as it leaves the gun.*

My solution uses the Principle of the Conservation of Momentum.

$$ m_1u_1 + m_2u_2 = m_1v_1 + m_2(v_2 + 2)$$

$m_1 =$ mass of gun and carriage and
$m_2 =$ mass of shell (which is in the gun).  Both $m_1$ and $m_2$ are traveling at $2\;m/s$.

$$ (10 \times 10^3)(2) + 50(2) = m_1v_1 + m_2(v_2 + 2)$$

Gun and carriage come to rest i.e. $v_1 = 0$, and the shell leaves the gun with a speed of $ (v_2 + 2)$.  The $2$ is added to $v_2$ since it is originally moving with a speed of $2\;m/s$.

$$ (10 \times 10^3)(2) + 50(2) =  (10 \times 10^3)(0) + (50) (v_2 + 2)$$
$$ 20,000 + 100 = 0 + (50) (v_2 + 2)$$
$$ 20,100 =  (50) (v_2 + 2)$$
$$ 402 = v_2 + 2 $$
$$ v_2 = 400$$

The shell leaves the gun at $400 \;m/s$.

Is my logic correct?  Or is there a twist in this question I cannot see.  BTW the question was worth 6 marks out of 100 marks total.

Thanks

Comment: Seems ok. Small correction in text: last word in problem statement should be 'gun', not 'shell'. Also, reads better if you write your first momentum equation with $v_2 + 2$ instead of just $v_2$. But the logic is fine.

Comment: Thanks Saeed.  I was concerned since the problem was worth a whopping 6 marks and the question seemed so straight forward.  Cheers.  PS thanks for the proof reading.